# Meaning of “en” in “il en est un …”

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, poésie, en

> Mais parmi les chacals, les panthères, les lices,
> Les singes, les scorpions, les vautours, les serpents,
> Les monstres glapissants, hurlants, grognants, rampants,
> Dans la ménagerie infâme de nos vices,
>
> II **en** est un plus laid, plus méchant, plus immonde!

Does the **en** in the last verse of this quotation from [*Au Lecteur*](http://fleursdumal.org/poem/099) refer to the *ménagerie infâme* in the previous verse? I'm asking this because, upon repeated reading of this fragment, I don't know what other word the **en** might actually be doubling.

Comment: Before anyone else gets here and says that this is too localized, I will suggest that you edit your post to ask about usage of the preposition en, and then give this as an example - and edit your title accordingly.  I think that would reduce any sort of controversy/discussion over this.

Comment: Theoretically, I know everything about _en_. Only _theoretically_, that is. Unfortunately, it's quite difficult to synchronize the theory you know with the actual reality (written or spoken) of the language. Case in point here. No matter how hard I tried to understand what this _en_ doubles, I have failed. So asking about usage of the word would be totally useless. I have my grammar for that. But the reality of the language is much bigger than any grammar can cover. So... do you see my dilemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word [*en*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) is one of those little words that has many different meanings.

Here, *en* is a pronoun. It does not refer to *la ménagerie*, but rather to *nos vices*.

I suspect that the biggest difficulty in this sentence is *il est*. This is a decidedly old-fashioned way of writing *il y a*. The pronoun *il* is impersonal, it does not have a referent. This formulation would not be used today, but it is not out of place in 19th century poetry. Hence, *il en est* means *il y en a*, i.e. “there is one (vice)”. Also, “*Il en est un plus laid […]*” is elided from “*Il en est un **qui est** plus laid […]*”

If read as prose, the sentence construction would be considered slightly awkward. Here is a decidedly non-poetic way to write this sentence:

*Nos vices constituent une ménagerie infâme. On peut les comparer à des chacals, […], à des monstres qui glapissent ou qui hurlent ou qui grognent ou qui rampent. Parmi ces vices, l'un d'entre eux est plus laid, plus méchant et plus immonde que les autres.*

Comment: Thank you. My curiosity is so ferocious that I simply can't help myself opening all sorts of books that are still technically inaccessible to me. So basically _il en est_ is an archaic way of saying _il y en a_ (which on www.collinsdictionaries.com is translated as _there is / there are_). I'm already learning so much from all of you. The more I read, the more I know (through my personal study and my asking questions on this site). But this is my method of learning French: learning through reading in French.

Answer (score 2):

La construction sous-jacente est « *il est [quelque chose] parmi [d'autres]* ». Lorsque le *il* est impersonnel on s'attend à ce que la phrase ait un complément. Tourné autrement, cela peut donner :

> **Parmi** ceux-ci, **il est** un animal¹ plus laid, méchant,… [que les autres].

On peut aussi utiliser le pronom *un* directement (comme dans le poème), et il est dans ce cas assorti d'un pronom *en*, cela donne :

> **Parmi** les animaux, il **en** est **un** plus laid,…

La même construction est possible avec le partitif :

> **Des** animaux, il en est un plus laid…

Ce qui explique d'une certaine manière la reprise faite par le pronom *en*.

—
<sup>1. À remplacer par *vice* pour ceux qui seraient de l'autre côté de la méthaphore. La construction s'appuie pourtant sur l'énumération.</sup>

Comment: Ah non, ce ne sont pas les animaux, ce sont les vices. Les vices sont comparés à des animaux, mais sans implication d'exclusivité — l'ennui est un vice mais pas forcément un animal.

Comment: Hein ? Les animaux c'est juste une métaphore, je comprends « dans la ménagerie infâme de nos vices » comme une incise. À quoi sert donc le début de la phrase sinon ? Si tu écris seulement « *Dans [blabla], il en est un…* » ça ne me parait pas tout à fait français.

Comment: Bien sûr que c'est une métaphore. Il y a des vices qui sont (comparés à) des chacals, et des vices qui sont des lices, etc. En fin de compte, l'ennui est un vice. C'est *vices* qui est antécédent de *en*, et pas l'énumération métaphorique ni *ménagerie*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Always grateful for a clear explanation.