# What is the role of “en” in “il en est de la solidité de”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> [Il en est de la solidité des machines-outils «made in Germany» comme
>   de la popularité d'Angela ­Merkel.](http://www.lefigaro.fr/international/2013/07/30/01003-20130730ARTFIG00453-au-faite-de-sa-popularite-merkel-domine-l-allemagne.php)

Does *en* in this context have anything to do with *en* in [this context](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/meaning-of-en-in-il-en-est-un)? Or does it mean something else altogether?

Also, I can see that *en* in this context plays a certain role in the comparison between the solidity of the *machines-outils* and the popularity of the German *Kanzlerin*, but don't know what that is.

Comment: Reading the context, I realize it can be a bit more general than “is at stake“ in fact. It's some kind of impersonal “it pertains to …”, “it concerns …”. Difficult to translate, it is [this kind of situational *en*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/la-provenance-lintuition-de-en-dans-les-expressions-idiomatiques#comment11071_6707).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Il en est ... comme de ...* is actually a comparison. This means, depending of the context, *these two things are doing as well as each other* or *these two things are working the same way*.

In this article,

> Il en est de la solidité des machines-outils «made in Germany» comme de la popularité d'Angela ­Merkel. Le temps ne les use pas.

could be rewritten this way:

> La solidité des machines-outils «made in Germany» et la popularité d'Angela ­Merkel sont comparables : le temps ne les use pas.